# Rename folders and filenames using os.walk()

Tags: python

I have a folder that has several folders and files in itself with the character "~" in the folder name or in the file name.
I need to replace or remove the character "~" in the foldernames and filenames.

```
import os

paths = (os.path.join(root, filename)
        for root, _, filenames in os.walk('x:\\')
        for filename in filenames)

# The keys of the dictionary are the values to replace, each corresponding
# item is the string to replace it with
replacements = {'~': ''}

for path in paths:
    # Copy the path name to apply changes (if any) to
    newname = path 
    # Loop over the dictionary elements, applying the replacements
    for k, v in replacements.items():
        newname = newname.replace(k, v)
    if newname != path:
        os.rename(path, newname)
```

I expected the code above to rename but istead it says: "Path not found"
Let's say i have this path: "x:\ajaxgo~1.com\ajax\libs\jquery\110.2\jquery~1.js" pythonscript will rename everyting right and generate it like this "x:\ajaxgo1.com\ajax\libs\jquery\110.2\jquery1.js" but os.rename() fails and can't find the path.

Comment: what gets printed when you add `print (path)` as the first line in your loop?

Comment: Well, `x:\ajaxgo1.com` doen't exist - you didn't rename that folder at any point in the walk, because you're only looking at the names of files, not folders.

Comment: @cptwonton: x:\contents.htm
x:\ajaxgo~1.com\ajax\libs\jquery\110.2\jquery~1.js then it fails and can't find the path.

Comment: @jasonharper I have both the foldername and filename in path variable. It renames both.

Comment: @Fusecube You can't rename files *and* folders/directories simultaneously.  You can rename only the right-most component of a path.

Comment: @jamesdlin Okay then I need to do one thing at a time. I first rename the folders then the files.

Comment: Personally I'd rename the files first (i.e., rename the deepest parts of the directory tree first) to ensure that it doesn't interfere with iterating through the tree.